# Resharper: how to see only particular group of members

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

I'm using shortcut alt+\ to list all members in file.
Is it a way to list only **specified type of members** (properties, methods, fields ...)

Sometime this is very useful

Eg DPack can do that by alt-p (props), alt-m (methods)

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do is use [Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/) to add regions based on member types (it's highly configurable). After that I can open ReSharper's File Structure Window to see the members organized by region. The regions can be collapsed independently in the File Structure Window.

Comment: This is one of solution but I'd prefer to see it in R# build search window (without using any additional tools)

Comment: @Maciej: I'd like to see that too. Why not put in a feature request to JetBrains? See http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-279