# Is there a method/function list feature in Resharper?

Tags: list, resharper, methods

With R# is there a way to view/nav the set of methods in the current class?

I know you can use VS' native top-right drop-down but I'd like a shortcut.

This seems like an obvious feature for R# as it's something I miss most in VS compared to other programmer's editors.

Thanks,
Matt

(ps. sorry if this post appears twice but first attempt didn't seem to post successfully)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two ways I use to navigate methods using R# are:

- ReSharper->Go To->File member... (Alt + \, for me)
- ReSharper->Windows->File Structure Window

The former invokes a popup with autocomplete where you can type the name of the method, or you can scroll through the list. The latter option is a window that provides an overview of the members in your class in the order they come in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I posted similar thread few months ago:

[Resharper: how to see only particular group of members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470414/resharper-how-to-see-only-particular-group-of-members)

Vote for particular members browsing feature if you'd like:

http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-279

Answer (score 0):

Resharper 2017.2 introduces [navigation filters](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/31/resharper-2017-2-whats-new-navigation) this allows you to filter methods "globally".

1. Resharper -> Navigate -> Search everywhere/Go to Type (Ctrl + T)
2. Type in **/mm** in the search box (this is the method filter mask).